# Replace the file from URL to raw folder

Tags: android, file, android-file

guys i have a text file in my URL.On click of a button i am able to download it to sdcard.

But i need to replace the downloaded file with the file in raw folder.Both are different files.

this is how i am downloading from URL

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/varun");
dir.mkdirs();
try {
    u = new URL("http://hihowru.com/123.xml");
            file = new File(dir,"123.xml");
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                   Log.d("DownloadManager", "download begining");
                   Log.d("DownloadManager", "download url:" + url);
                   Log.d("DownloadManager", "downloaded file name:" + "a.mp3");
        URLConnection uconnection = u.openConnection();
        InputStream is = uconnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                    baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
                       int current = 0;
                       while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                          baf.append((byte) current);
                       }

                FileOutputStream fos;

                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloaded to Sdcard/varun"+audioxml, 0);
                toast.show();
                Log.d("DownloadManager", "download ready in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");
                Intent ii = new Intent(DownloadFiles.this,Relaxation.class);
                startActivity(ii);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but i need to replace this file(downloaded file) with the file in raw folder

download file name : hi.txt
raw folder name : hw.txt

how to acheive this please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178873/how-to-overwrite-a-text-file-programmatically, there is one post for rewriting the file you can refer this

Answer (score 0):

**You can't** modify or write a file in `android resources` or `asset` directory. Because of android apk file is `read only`. So you are able to only read it. Best way is copy that file in `internal storage` then use from that path, also after download file from url update that at internal storage path.

**Update:**

Code for copy file from /asset to application internal storage.

```
private void copyFile(String filename) {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(filename);
        String newFileName = "/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + filename;
        out = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: problem is i already have a default file in app i just need to replace the downloaded file

Comment: so i can copy to internal storage data/data... but how to update my app ? please help

Comment: You can't. You have to copy that file to other place then use it from there.

Comment: briefly i will explain :i have an activity where i have a default file loaded from raw folder.In that activity i have a button onclick of button it will show avaliable files From URL to download.when i click one among them it will downlaod into sdcard into folder varun.Now  what i need to do is replace downloaded file with default file

Comment: now simply, put your available file in /asset folder when your application launch first time copy it to /data/data/<package_name>/files directory and also when you download file from url put those file in same directory. you can also make a directory in files directory.

Comment: U mean to say when i first launch my app copy file from raw to data/data.. and then when i download it from url put it into same directory ...but how will it help me in replacing files

Comment: is it necessary to put file in raw directory? Asset is also there.

Comment: firstly thank u for patience and time .Fine i have added into assets folder now how shall i go about?please help